# Create access token for Google Bigquery using JWT with python

Tags: python, authentication, google-bigquery, jwt

I am trying to get access token for bigquery using JWT method with python. New access token will be used to access bigquery. But while trying to get new access token it is showing error 401. I am not sure how to resolve this error. Following files I have used to create the scenario.

jwt.py

```
import google.auth.jwt as jwt
import google.auth.crypt
import time
import json
import requests


now = int(time.time())
sa_email = ''# service account
audience = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
sa_keyfile = 'key.json'
# build payload
payload = {
    'iat': now,
    # expires after 'expiry_length' seconds.
    "exp": now + 3600,
    'iss': sa_email,
    'aud': audience,
    'sub': sa_email,
    'email': sa_email
}

# sign with keyfile
signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file(sa_keyfile)
jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)
print(jwt)
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jwt.decode('utf-8')),
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
    }

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.status_code, response.content)
token = response.json()['access_token']
print('token : ', token)
response.raise_for_status()
```

requirements.txt

```
asttokens==2.0.5
backcall==0.2.0
cachetools==5.2.0
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
click==8.1.3
debugpy==1.6.2
decorator==5.1.1
entrypoints==0.4
executing==0.8.3
Flask==2.1.2
google-auth==2.9.1
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
ipykernel==6.15.1
ipython==8.4.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
jupyter-client==7.3.4
jupyter-core==4.11.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.5
packaging==21.3
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==3.0.30
psutil==5.9.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
Pygments==2.12.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pyzmq==23.2.0
requests==2.28.1
rsa==4.8
six==1.16.0
stack-data==0.3.0
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.3.0
urllib3==1.26.10
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zipp==3.8.0
```

But I am getting this error :

```
<Response [401]>
401 b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 401,\n    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Invalid Credentials",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "authError",\n        "location": "Authorization",\n        "locationType": "header"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"\n  }\n}\n'
token :  {'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.', 'errors': [{'message': 'Invalid Credentials', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'authError', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}], 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 39, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/workspace/datastudio-poc/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects
```

Please suggest something and thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try validating the JWT token by checking whether it contains valid JSON or not using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). You need to make an authenticated request to API for which you can follow the steps given in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request). For creating JWT token you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#creating_jwts) . Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi NIKHIL PIMPARE, did the above comment help?

Comment: Hi @NIKHIL PIMPARE, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

JWT tokens are used to authenticate users in GCP where a client application sends JSON Web Token for authentication. For creating JWT tokens, you can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#creating_jwts).

According to the error mentioned, you can first try validating the JWT token whether the token contains valid JSON or not for which you can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).
You need to make an authenticated request to API by creating a JWT and sign it with service accounts private key and send the signed JWT as a request to the API. For more details, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request).